# Using ng-bind-html is hiding words enclosed in "<>"

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to create a textbox that takes free text, and shows the text as output. For instance, if I enter `"Angular"`, the result should be **Angular**. It should appear as is regardless of the characters being used.

For this, I'm using `ng-bind-html`. The issue I'm seeing is, whenever I add a term enclosed in `"<>"`, the term doesn't appear as a whole. For example, if I enter `"<Angular>"` the result is `""`.

How can I display words enclosed in `"<>"` without using `ng-bind-html`, but getting the same results?

Comment: how exactly do you want it to be displayed? `ng-bind-html` will render it as HTML code, where `<Angular>` is considered as one of the tags (same will happen with `$compile` in directives).

Comment: You can add &lt;Angular&gt; if you just to want to show <Angular> as text. See eample: https://plnkr.co/edit/xqsjH1AQCvomSqBQh22U?p=preview

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I want it to be displayed with the tags intact, but the code is treating`<Angular>` as an HTML tag.

Comment: @SehaxX that worked like a charm. Could you please add your comment as a separate answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to encode/decode the tag like <Angular> if you just to want to show  as text.

```
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

And in controller:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML =
       'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>&lt;Angular&gt;';
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: This would be hardcoding the output, no? My purpose is to show the entered words with the characters. It should be dynamic.